# Change name server (www.eatj.com)

Tags: nameserver

I hosted my website [www.thakormatrimony.com](http://www.thakormatrimony.com) on [www.eatj.com](http://www.eatj.com) . The website was working fine for last two years, but now [www.eatj.com](http://www.eatj.com) 's server is hacked and my website is down since 3 month. I tried to contact them on email and phone but they don't respond so I've to run my website on another server.

How could I identify, is the name server data on [www.eatj.com](http://www.eatj.com) it self or they are using other service for name server? If they are using other service for the name server, then how could I find the service provider name, to contact them and update it?

Comment: http://www.whois.com Looks you are in trouble. However, the domain will expire at the end of this year.

Comment: best way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know where you register your domain name ? If you registered and hosted @ eatj.com. Then try to contact GoDaddy may be they guys help you because eatj.com it registered at GoDaddy. 
Hope it will help you..

Comment: i registered it via eatj.com

Comment: Then try to get help from GoDaddy US..